# Changing interpolation to bezier makes rotation go backwards

Tags: animation

I have this problem when rotating this gear on y axis with a linear interpolation. It seems no problems, but when I change it to bezier interpolation, the inside rotates fine, but the outside of the gear seems to be rotating backward, which is a strange effect. Even if its the same object.
And I want it to work with bezier interpolation, not linear!

You can download the blend file here:

[blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A2fs7kjF7HaNY7H0kkFq8ROrG0I-8PFJ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: You may be seeing the [wagon wheel effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagon-wheel_effect)

Comment: well if its was that changing the interpolation from bezier to linear well not make any difference

Answer (score 2):

As batFINGER mentioned, you are indeed seeing the wagon wheel effect. I can prove this in several ways.

If you modify the gear by adding an irregularity at one point on one of the teeth or any other way that makes one single point on the gear different from the rest of the gear, and then play the animation, you will see that the point rotates properly, meaning that all the teeth are.

This is directly caused by switching to bezier interpolation as the bezier interpolation causes the gear to rotate faster for most of the animation than the linear interpolation does. This increase in speed is what is causing the effect. If you have linear interpolation and simply increase the speed of the rotation by moving the second keyframe back to frame 190 the effect will be permanent. If you move the second keyframe forwards and backwards, you can observe all kinds of interesting results.

If this effect is undesired, you could avoid it by changing the rotation speed. However, since this is a real world effect, I personally wouldn't worry about it. It's clear at the start and end of the animation that the gear is turning a certain way.

**EDIT:** You mentioned that you see this effect when going frame by frame, and that is actually expected. It's simply a result of the rotational speed of the gear. The speed is such that after one frame of rotation, the gear appears to have rotated backwards slightly. What has actually happened is the gear has rotated forwards and simply ended up in a spot that makes it appear as if it had rotated backwards. I think making the gear not so perfect would be the best way for you to visualize this, at least to understand what's going on here. You could even apply a procedural texture to the gear, anything that makes the gear less perfect. Anything that your eyes can identify as a unique point on the gear will make this problem disappear.

If you are still unsure that this is in fact the issue, try adjusting the speed of the animation by moving the second keyframe around. At very slow speeds, you will see it behave as expected, then as you speed it up, the outer teeth will appear to slow down and then begin to rotate backwards. This is the wagon wheel effect, and it's just an optical illusion.

Comment: thank you for your commnet but still dosent make sense to me i know in fact that i should see this effect at  high speed rotation  so that mean if it's indeed a wagon wheel effect i should not see the gear rotate backwards when i jump frame by frame

Comment: i research in the net about this some mention gimbal lock and stuff but im not sure even that lead to other problem and i just want simple rotation with a bezier interpolation !

Comment: @montif See the edit I made to my post. Hopefully that clears it up a bit for you. You have the bezier interpolated rotation that you want, it just doesn't appear that way. If you want to get rid of this effect, try playing around with the animation speed or giving the gear some sort of unevenness, perhaps a metal texture or something similar.

Comment: indeed i try it by my self i assign a different material to a single gear tooth and appears that was true is was an illusion after all    even though knowing the problem doesn't solve it   the problem that i want match a sound track with the rotation of the gear and the sound is like this ( goes fast and slows dramatically at the end )   i watched many gear rotation videos but no one of them have this effect even they rotate faster but in blender just making the gear rotate more than 360° you start saying that funky rotation i cant say none realistic because it seems that how things goes !